# Which devices support remote control event in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4

I am trying to perform a function from a bluetooth device(Apple Wireless keyboard etc.) I implemented UIControlEvent on key press but no events are received. Is it possible to receive events on a click of any button on bluetooth device?

Answer (score 1):

With Bluetooth LE it should be possible. You have to implement the 
*- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error* of the CBPeripheralDelegate protocol. This message will send to the delegate object after your device has added a peripheral and and the method discoverService: was sended